# Search value in a java list by some of its fields

Tags: java, list, search, arraylist

Good morning. Currently I have the following java class of which I have a list of identities:

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@RegisterForReflection
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
public class Identity {

    private String type;
    private String id;
    @JsonIgnore
    private String account;
    private List<String> services;
    private List<String> roles;
}
```

Currently I have a List of Identity (**`List <Identity>`**) and I need to search within this list for some or all of its parameters, that is, I can have the following use cases for searching for an identity within the list:

```
 1. type && id;
 2. type && id && services; 
 3. type && id && services && roles;
```

How can I do in this case? I know that lists have methods like contains, but I don't know if they apply to partial searches like I want, what I want is that if it makes a match it returns the element

Comment: Can you share some input/output examples please

Comment: You have to write code to search a list for an element that matches your search criteria.  Probably the easiest approach is to write a comparator (or similar) for each distinct set of search criteria, and then iterate through the list using the specific comparator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you need something like this:

```
public Identity findIdentity(List<Identity> identities, String type, String id, List<String> services, List<String> roles) {
    return identities.stream()
            .filter(identity -> isCorrectIdentity(type, id, services, roles, identity))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
}

private boolean isCorrectIdentity(String type, String id, List<String> services, List<String> roles, Identity identity) {
    return identity.getType().equals(type) && identity.getId().equals(id) &&
            (services == null || new HashSet<>(identity.getServices()).containsAll(services)) &&
            (roles == null || new HashSet<>(identity.getRoles()).containsAll(roles));
}
```

This will loop over your list, check element by element the type and id and if the services are defined it will check also with services and in the end if the roles are defined it will search by roles.

Note: you can simplify the `isCorrectIdentity` by using multiple `if elses` or multiples `methods`.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with the [Java Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html).

For example, given a `List<Identity>` called `identities` you can do:

```
identities.stream()
  .filter(identity -> identity.getType().equals(type) && identity.getId().equals(id))
  .findFirst();
```

I'd be tempted to move the predicate logic to the `Identity` class, so you'd have something like:

```
public class Identity {

  private String type;
  private String id;
  private String account;
  private List<String> services;
  private List<String> roles;

  public boolean matches(string type, string id, string service, string role) {
     return (type == null || this.type.equals(type)) && 
       (id == null || this.id.equals(id)) && 
       (service == null || this.services.contains(service)) &&
       (role == null || this.roles.contains(role));  
  }
}
```

Which would then be used like this:

```
identities.stream()
  .filter(identity -> identity.matches(type, id, service, role))
  .findFirst();
```